# Is Microsoft SQL Server Express available for production in Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET Core app to Linux for production. My question is, is Microsoft SQL Server Express available for production in Linux? Or do I have to use the paid version?

Comment: You got a +1 from me. Don't know why all the hate for this question. I had the exact same question for a hobby project of mine getting a cheap database up and running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL Server Express can be used in production (beware of the limitations, like the 10GB cap), but according to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2017) Express is available for Linux.

Comment: The link you share is about SQL Server 2017, not the Express version.

Comment: Like @RoniTovi , I can not find a download link or anything. The only thing, which points in the direction of SQL Server Express being available for Linux is, that Linux is mentioned in the Title and the Express-Version is discussed in the content. Can you please be more specific

Answer (score 8):

## SQL Server Express is available for Linux

As discussed in [Install Microsoft SQL Server 2017 on Fedora 29/CentOS 7](https://kifarunix.com/install-microsoft-sql-server-2017-on-fedora-29-centos-7/), just install the `mssql-server` package and choose "3) Express (free)" in the configuration step.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server Express is available to use in Production. It's just restricted by the DB size (10GB) and doesn't come with some other features, like SQL Agent, High availability, transparent data encryption, etc...